# can't view a listview inside a listview correctly in android app

Tags: android, listview, android-layout, android-listview

I want to display data from a very generic JSON string in my android app. One view/screen shall display an arbitrary number of "details" where each detail has an arbitrary number of "values".

I'm trying to use a ListView inside a Listview, and all the data is nicely put into each list, but the lists won't display fully (see image below).

In the lower part of the screen is the first ListView. It contains a number of TextView labels (e.g. Usage and Info), which in turn has a number of values (units, sw version etc). The values is put in a new list which displays a TextView.

The top part is also a ListView, but is displayed ok.

Looks like this:

First part, status tab with the two lists, first (fine) and second (problem):

```
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/tabStatus">

        <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/listThingStatus"/>

        <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/listThingDetails"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

The lower ListView with the label and the second ListView:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="70px">    
                <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content">      
                    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="30px" android:id="@+id/textDetails" />  
                    <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/listThingValues"/>                                                   
                </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

And finally the TextViews inside the second ListView:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="70px">    
                <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_vertical">
                    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="30px" android:id="@+id/textValuesLabel" />        
                    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="30px" android:gravity="right|center" android:id="@+id/textValuesUnits" />    
                </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

The result is this (see image), where the content in the inner lists is mostly "hidden" (SW version and text below etc). I use "wrap_content" almost everywhere but the content is too wrapped here :(. How and where do I format my XML to make the content in the inner lists display properly?

Image (from emulator, but same result on phone):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVGCz.png

Comment: Have you considered using an ExpandableListview instead of nesting your listviews the way you've done?

Comment: The android app should have the same look as the equivalent iPhone app, so that list type is not an option at the moment. Will suggest this though. Thanks!

Comment: you can customize the look of the expandable list however you want, do you mind explaining how it is not applicable in this case?

Comment: perhaps if you show us a screenshot of the iphone app, someone will know how to recreate it for android

Comment: I've decided to use only one list and add rows dynamically instead (see below). Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placing a `ListView` inside a `ListView` will only bring you headaches.

Try using an [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) instead.

Comment: Hehe. As I said above, not an option right now. Will continue to try and make the current lists work until I'm allowed to use another look for the layout. Thanks!

Comment: @Christoffer: If the second list have a *limited* amount of rows use a `LinearLayout` and add rows dynamically. If you need to place two `ListView` you will need to handle touches yourself. Trust me, that will only bring pain and misery :)

Comment: Ok, tried adding rows to a LinearLayout instead and skipped the second list, and it works much better. Thanks!